# public array loaded from useform vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, public

Iam creating a macro, and I need to access the array that is created and filled in useform (button_click action) in module.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim tmojo As Worksheet
Dim mojocell As Range

Set tmojo = Sheets("table mojo")
colls = tmojo.Range("N1").End(xlToLeft).Column

i = 1
For Each cCont In Me.Controls

 If TypeName(cCont) = "ComboBox" Then
    If cCont.Enabled = True Then
        If cCont.Value = Empty Then
            MsgBox "you havent specified all the columns"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ReDim Preserve collname(i)
        collname(i) = cCont.Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
 End If
Next cCont

Call createregion


End Sub
```

I fill the array collname with values from multiple comboboxes (column names). Then I want to call createregion sub which is located in module and I want to access the values in collname(). 
im getting error saying that:

`Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types, and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of an object module`

I need to access this array in multiple subs, is there any workaround?

Thank you in forehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to transfer your **UserForm code into a regular module**, and declare your array as public, on the top of the module, before every subs :

```
Public MyArr()
```

When you transfer your code, you will need to **call the subs into your UserForm's events**, and so **change all the `Me` and `Me.` to the full name of your UserForm**.

And if you are lacking time, you can simply declare on the top of the UserForm module :

```
Dim MyArr()
```